# JQuery Can't Copy From 1 Input to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to copy one value from `<input>` field value to another using jQuery.

This works in JSFiddle But does not work when I try it on my local server.

what am I doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/1emrxsLw/

**JS:**

```
$('#do').click(function() {
   $('#three').val($('#one').val());
});

$('#four').keyup(function() {
   $('#six').val($('#four').val());
});

$('#seven').blur(function() {
  $('#nine').val($('#seven').val());
});
```

Complete HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Button Click</h1>
<form id="form1">
  <input id='one' type='text' />
  <input id='two' type='text' />
</form>

<form id="form2">
  <input id='three' type='text' />
</form>

<input type='button' id="do" value="Copy" />

<h1>Insta-Copy(TM)</h1>
<form id="form1">
  <input id='four' type='text' />
  <input id='five' type='text' />
</form>

<form id="form2">
  <input id='six' type='text' />
</form>



<h1>On Blur</h1>
<form id="form1">
  <input id='seven' type='text' />
  <input id='eight' type='text' />
</form>

<form id="form2">
  <input id='nine' type='text' />
</form>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#do').click(function() {
  $('#pDate1').val($('#fdatea').val());
});

$('#four').keyup(function() {
  $('#six').val($('#four').val());
});

$('#seven').blur(function() {
  $('#nine').val($('#seven').val());
});
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: You use `#pDate1` instead of `#three` in `$('#do').click()`

Comment: Your fiddle looks fine.

Comment: Apart from the errors that @Moshe mentions, there are more errors in your HTML. Script elements can only occur in the head or in the body. Form elements require action attributes. And a couple of errors that are caused by your choice of doctype...

Answer (score 2):

First, id attributes in HTML page suppose to be unique to that page, you can't have multiple id values within the page, and you do have. for example:

```
<form id="form1">
  <input id='four' type='text' />
  <input id='five' type='text' />
</form>
```

and:

```
<form id="form1">
  <input id='seven' type='text' />
  <input id='eight' type='text' />
</form>
```

The forms have identical id values, and that's a bad practice.

Second, you posted to javascript files, which one are you actually using?

I tested for you the first js script:

```
$('#do').click(function() {
   $('#three').val($('#one').val());
});

$('#four').keyup(function() {
   $('#six').val($('#four').val());
});

$('#seven').blur(function() {
  $('#nine').val($('#seven').val());
});
```

**That works fine.**

However, the second js file that you posted at the bottom of the HTML page won't do the job because it refers to id values which don't exist, like: `#pDate1` and `#fdatea`